# How to hide Status bar in iOS7 for only one controller?

Tags: ios, ios7, statusbar

I have inherited UITableViewController, I want status bar either hide or make it in white color so that I can see it, as its of black background in that tableview.

It looks like

[image: Image of Status Bar]

It would be either of white colour for only this controller, or hide totally.

Answer (score 1):

Implement this method in your `ViewController`

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

and call this method where you want at your `ViewController`.

```
[self prefersStatusBarHidden];
```

Comment: But also you should have "View controller-based status bar appearance"  setting in app-info.plist set to YES

Comment: Dear, that plist hides for all the controllers, i want only for one.

Comment: -1 what's the purpose of calling `[self prefersStatusBarHidden];`?